# Widget for collecting leads

Tags: javascript

I have JavaScript widget code for collecting leads:

```js
// Create an immediately invoked functional expression to wrap our code
(function() {

  // Define our constructor 
  this.Widget = function(options) {

    this.widgetWrap = null;
    this.widgetClose = null;
    this.widgetHeaderTitle = null;
    this.widgetInput = null;
    this.widgetFormInputError = null;
    this.widgetFormSubmit = null;
    this.titleAnimationInterval = null;
    this.overlay = null;
    this.formWrap = null;
    this.formIframe = null;

    this.images = {
      close: 'data:image/png;base64,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',
      loading: 'url(data:image/png;base64,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)',
      sprite: 'http://hotpartner.ru/forms/img/widget_sprite.png'
    };

    // Establish our default settings
    this.options = extend({
      formHeaders: ['Заголовок 1', 'Заголовок 2'],
      formText: 'Бесплатная консультация прямо у нас на сайте!',
      formPlaceholder: 'Введите Ваш вопрос...',
      color: '#336699',
      photo: 1,
      formPosition: 'right',
      transitionDuration: 150,
      questionMinLength: 15
    }, options);

    this.init();

  };

  // Public Methods

  Widget.prototype.init = function() {

    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    this.widgetWrap = document.createElement('div');
    this.widgetWrap.style.backgroundColor = this.options.color;
    this.widgetWrap.style.borderRadius = '3px 3px 0 0';
    this.widgetWrap.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';
    this.widgetWrap.style.color = '#fff';
    this.widgetWrap.style.font = '14px/1 Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif';
    this.widgetWrap.style.padding = '10px';
    this.widgetWrap.style.position = 'fixed';
    this.widgetWrap.style.width = '335px';
    this.widgetWrap.style.zIndex = 99999;
    this.widgetWrap.style.textAlign = 'left';
    this.widgetWrap.style[this.options.formPosition] = '10px';
    this.widgetWrap.style.bottom = '-185px';
    this.widgetWrap.style.transitionProperty = 'bottom';
    this.widgetWrap.style.transitionTimingFunction = 'ease-in';
    this.widgetWrap.style.transitionDuration = this.options.transitionDuration + 'ms';

    this.widgetClose = document.createElement('span');
    this.widgetClose.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + this.images.sprite + ')';
    this.widgetClose.style.backgroundColor = this.options.color;
    this.widgetClose.style.borderRadius = '50%';
    this.widgetClose.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    this.widgetClose.style.height = '20px';
    this.widgetClose.style.position = 'absolute';
    this.widgetClose.style.right = '-9px';
    this.widgetClose.style.top = '-9px';
    this.widgetClose.style.width = '20px';
    this.widgetClose.style.display = 'none';
    this.widgetClose.style.backgroundPosition = '5px -88px';
    this.widgetClose.onclick = this.toState.bind(this, 'mini');
    this.widgetWrap.appendChild(this.widgetClose);

    var widgetHeader = document.createElement('div');
    widgetHeader.style.marginBottom = '2px';
    widgetHeader.style.padding = '6px 0px 14px';
    widgetHeader.style.position = 'relative';
    widgetHeader.style.borderBottom = '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';
    widgetHeader.style.boxShadow = '0 2px 1px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)';
    widgetHeader.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    widgetHeader.onclick = this.slideToggle.bind(this);

    this.widgetHeaderTitle = document.createElement('div');
    this.widgetHeaderTitle.style.color = '#fff';
    this.widgetHeaderTitle.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + this.images.sprite + ')';
    this.widgetHeaderTitle.style.fontSize = '14px';
    this.widgetHeaderTitle.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    this.widgetHeaderTitle.style.paddingLeft = '27px';
    this.widgetHeaderTitle.style.textOverflow = 'ellipsis';
    this.widgetHeaderTitle.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';
    this.widgetHeaderTitle.style.lineHeight = 1;
    this.widgetHeaderTitle.style.height = '20px';
    this.widgetHeaderTitle.style.margin = '0px 10px';
    this.widgetHeaderTitle.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    this.widgetHeaderTitle.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
    this.widgetHeaderTitle.style.transitionProperty = 'opacity';
    this.widgetHeaderTitle.style.transitionTimingFunction = 'ease-in';
    this.widgetHeaderTitle.style.transitionDuration = this.options.transitionDuration + 'ms';
    this.widgetHeaderTitle.textContent = this.options.formHeaders[0];

    contentAnimation.call(this, this.widgetHeaderTitle, this.options.formHeaders);

    widgetHeader.appendChild(this.widgetHeaderTitle);

    this.widgetWrap.appendChild(widgetHeader);

    var widgetBody = document.createElement('div');
    widgetBody.style.marginBottom = '10px';
    widgetBody.style.padding = '10px';

    var div_5 = document.createElement('div');
    div_5.style.height = '55px';
    div_5.style.marginBottom = '20px';
    div_5.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    div_5.style.paddingLeft = '72px';
    div_5.style.position = 'relative';

    var div_6 = document.createElement('div');
    div_6.style.top = '0';
    div_6.style.left = '0';
    div_6.style.position = 'absolute';
    div_6.style.borderRadius = '10px';
    div_6.style.backgroundColor = '#66CC33';
    div_6.style.height = '6px';
    div_6.style.width = '6px';
    div_5.appendChild(div_6);

    var photoImg = document.createElement('img');
    photoImg.src = 'http://hotpartner.ru/forms/images/' + this.options.photo + '.png';
    photoImg.style.width = '52px';
    photoImg.style.height = '52px';
    photoImg.style.borderRadius = '50%';
    photoImg.style.margin = '-27px 0 0';
    photoImg.style.position = 'absolute';
    photoImg.style.left = '0';
    photoImg.style.top = '50%';
    photoImg.title = '';
    div_5.appendChild(photoImg);

    var div_8 = document.createElement('div');
    div_8.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)';
    div_8.style.borderRadius = '3px';
    div_8.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';
    div_8.style.color = '#fff';
    div_8.style.height = '53px';
    div_8.style.padding = '7px';
    div_8.style.position = 'relative';

    var i_0 = document.createElement('i');
    i_0.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + this.images.sprite + ')';
    i_0.style.height = '10px';
    i_0.style.left = '-13px';
    i_0.style.marginTop = '-15px';
    i_0.style.position = 'absolute';
    i_0.style.top = '50%';
    i_0.style.width = '14px';
    i_0.style.backgroundPosition = '0px -232px';
    i_0.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
    div_8.appendChild(i_0);

    var span_1 = document.createElement('span');
    span_1.style.display = 'block';
    span_1.style.height = '34px';
    span_1.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    span_1.style.lineHeight = '18px';
    span_1.textContent = this.options.formText;
    div_8.appendChild(span_1);

    div_5.appendChild(div_8);

    widgetBody.appendChild(div_5);

    this.widgetInput = document.createElement('textarea');
    this.widgetInput.maxLength = 768;
    this.widgetInput.rows = 1;
    this.widgetInput.style.color = '#333';
    this.widgetInput.style.resize = 'none';
    this.widgetInput.style.display = 'block';
    this.widgetInput.style.padding = '8px';
    this.widgetInput.style.width = '295px';
    this.widgetInput.style.border = '0';
    this.widgetInput.style.borderRadius = '3px';
    this.widgetInput.style.lineHeight = '16px';
    this.widgetInput.style.fontFamily = 'Arial, sans-serif';
    this.widgetInput.style.fontSize = '14px';
    this.widgetInput.style.margin = '1px 0px';
    this.widgetInput.style.boxShadow = '-2px 2px 3px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)';
    this.widgetInput.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';
    this.widgetInput.style.background = 'url(' + this.images.sprite + ') no-repeat scroll right -251px #fff';
    this.widgetInput.style.height = '35px';
    this.widgetInput.style.overflowX = 'hidden';
    this.widgetInput.style.overflowY = 'auto';
    this.widgetInput.style.transitionProperty = 'height';
    this.widgetInput.style.transitionTimingFunction = 'ease-in';
    this.widgetInput.style.transitionDuration = this.options.transitionDuration + 'ms';
    this.widgetInput.placeholder = this.options.formPlaceholder;
    this.widgetInput.onclick = this.toState.bind(this, 'full');
    this.widgetInput.onblur = this.slideToggle.bind(this);
    widgetBody.appendChild(this.widgetInput);

    this.widgetFormInputError = document.createElement('div');
    this.widgetFormInputError.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFF66';
    this.widgetFormInputError.style.border = '1px solid #CCCC00';
    this.widgetFormInputError.style.borderRadius = '0 0 4px 4px';
    this.widgetFormInputError.style.boxSizing = 'content-box';
    this.widgetFormInputError.style.color = '#000';
    this.widgetFormInputError.style.height = '20px';
    this.widgetFormInputError.style.marginTop = '-31px';
    this.widgetFormInputError.style.padding = '5px 0px';
    this.widgetFormInputError.style.position = 'absolute';
    this.widgetFormInputError.style.textAlign = 'center';
    this.widgetFormInputError.style.opacity = 0;
    this.widgetFormInputError.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    this.widgetFormInputError.style.width = '293px';
    this.widgetFormInputError.style.fontSize = '12px';
    this.widgetFormInputError.style.lineHeight = '20px';
    this.widgetFormInputError.style.fontStyle = 'italic';
    this.widgetFormInputError.style.transitionProperty = 'opacity';
    this.widgetFormInputError.style.transitionTimingFunction = 'ease-in';
    this.widgetFormInputError.style.transitionDuration = this.options.transitionDuration + 'ms';
    this.widgetFormInputError.textContent = 'Опишите, пожалуйста, подробнее ваш вопрос.';
    widgetBody.appendChild(this.widgetFormInputError);

    this.widgetWrap.appendChild(widgetBody);

    var widgetForm = document.createElement('div');
    widgetForm.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    widgetForm.style.paddingRight = '120px';
    widgetForm.style.position = 'relative';

    var widgetFormLabel = document.createElement('span');
    widgetFormLabel.style.background = 'url(' + this.images.sprite + ') no-repeat scroll 0 -52px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)';
    widgetFormLabel.style.display = 'block';
    widgetFormLabel.style.height = '28px';
    widgetFormLabel.style.paddingLeft = '30px';
    widgetFormLabel.style.marginLeft = '10px';
    widgetFormLabel.innerHTML = 'Онлайн<br>Консультация';
    widgetForm.appendChild(widgetFormLabel);

    this.widgetFormSubmit = document.createElement('button');
    this.widgetFormSubmit.style.position = 'absolute';
    this.widgetFormSubmit.style.right = '0';
    this.widgetFormSubmit.style.top = '0';
    this.widgetFormSubmit.style.width = '120px';
    this.widgetFormSubmit.style.height = '26px';
    this.widgetFormSubmit.style.border = '0';
    this.widgetFormSubmit.style.borderTop = '1px solid #afe18a';
    this.widgetFormSubmit.style.borderRadius = '3px';
    this.widgetFormSubmit.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';
    this.widgetFormSubmit.style.font = 'bold 14px/1.4 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif';
    this.widgetFormSubmit.style.textShadow = '0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5)';
    this.widgetFormSubmit.style.color = 'white';
    this.widgetFormSubmit.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    this.widgetFormSubmit.style.outline = 'none';
    this.widgetFormSubmit.style.backgroundColor = '#66CC33';
    this.widgetFormSubmit.style.marginRight = '10px';
    this.widgetFormSubmit.type = 'submit';
    this.widgetFormSubmit.textContent = 'Отправить';
    this.widgetFormSubmit.onclick = this.send.bind(this);
    widgetForm.appendChild(this.widgetFormSubmit);

    this.widgetWrap.appendChild(widgetForm);

    fragment.appendChild(this.widgetWrap);

    this.overlay = document.createElement('div');
    this.overlay.style.zIndex = '2147483646';
    this.overlay.style.display = 'none';
    this.overlay.style.position = 'fixed';
    this.overlay.style.background = 'rgba(0,0,0,.5)';
    this.overlay.style.width = '100%';
    this.overlay.style.height = '100%';
    this.overlay.style.top = '0';
    this.overlay.style.left = '0';
    this.overlay.onclick = this.formHide.bind(this);

    fragment.appendChild(this.overlay);

    this.formWrap = document.createElement('div');
    this.formWrap.style.zIndex = '2147483647';
    this.formWrap.style.display = 'none';
    this.formWrap.style.position = 'fixed';
    this.formWrap.style.borderRadius = '3px';
    this.formWrap.style.background = '#fff';
    this.formWrap.style.backgroundImage = this.images.loading;
    this.formWrap.style.backgroundPosition = 'center';
    this.formWrap.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
    this.formWrap.style.margin = 'auto';
    this.formWrap.style.boxShadow = '0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5)';
    this.formWrap.style.transform = 'translate(-50%,-50%)';
    this.formWrap.style.top = '50%';
    this.formWrap.style.left = '50%';

    var formClose = document.createElement('img');
    formClose.src = this.images.close;
    formClose.style.position = 'absolute';
    formClose.style.right = '0';
    formClose.style.margin = '-15px -15px 0 0';
    formClose.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    formClose.onclick = this.formHide.bind(this);
    this.formWrap.appendChild(formClose);

    this.formIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    this.formIframe.urlBase = 'http://hotpartner.ru/forms/form.min.htm';
    this.formIframe.width = 400;
    this.formIframe.height = 530;
    this.formIframe.style.border = '0';
    this.formIframe.style.margin = '1px';
    this.formWrap.appendChild(this.formIframe);

    fragment.appendChild(this.formWrap);

    document.body.appendChild(fragment);
  };

  Widget.prototype.slideToggle = function() {
    if (this.widgetInput.value) {
      this.toState('full');
    } else {
      this.toState('expanded');
    }
  };

  Widget.prototype.toState = function(state) {
    switch (state) {
      case 'mini':
        this.widgetWrap.style.bottom = '-185px';
        this.widgetClose.style.display = 'none';

        this.widgetInput.style.height = '35px';
        this.widgetInput.style.background = 'url(' + this.images.sprite + ') no-repeat scroll right -251px #fff';

        contentAnimation.call(this, this.widgetHeaderTitle, this.options.formHeaders);
        break;
      case 'expanded':
        this.widgetWrap.style.bottom = '-39px';
        this.widgetClose.style.display = '';

        this.widgetInput.style.height = '35px';
        this.widgetInput.style.background = 'url(' + this.images.sprite + ') no-repeat scroll right -251px #fff';

        clearInterval(this.titleAnimationInterval);
        break;
      case 'full':
        this.widgetWrap.style.bottom = '0';
        this.widgetClose.style.display = '';

        this.widgetInput.style.height = '80px';
        this.widgetInput.style.backgroundImage = 'none';

        clearInterval(this.titleAnimationInterval);
        break;
    }
  };

  Widget.prototype.send = function() {
    var self = this;
    if (self.widgetInput.value) {

      self.widgetInput.style.border = '0';
      self.widgetInput.style.boxShadow = '-2px 2px 3px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)';

      if (self.widgetInput.value.length < self.options.questionMinLength) {
        self.widgetFormInputError.style.opacity = 100;
        self.widgetFormInputError.style.visibility = 'visible';
        setTimeout(function() {
          self.widgetFormInputError.style.opacity = 0;
          self.widgetFormInputError.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }, 4000);
      } else {
        self.formUpdate();
        self.toState('mini');
        self.overlay.style.display = '';
        self.formWrap.style.display = '';
      }
    } else {
      self.widgetInput.style.borderColor = '#f00';
      self.widgetInput.style.boxShadow = '0 0 20px #f00';
    }
  };

  Widget.prototype.formHide = function() {
    this.overlay.style.display = 'none';
    this.formWrap.style.display = 'none';
  };

  Widget.prototype.formUpdate = function() {
    var url = this.formIframe.urlBase + '?q=' + encodeURI(this.widgetInput.value.substring(0, 768)) + '&partnerId=' + this.options.partnerId + '&channelId=' + this.options.channelId + '&departmentId=' + this.options.departmentId + '&referer=' + encodeURI(document.URL);
    this.formIframe.src = url;
  };

  // Private Methods

  function contentAnimation(el, arr) {
    var self = this;
    var current = 1;
    self.titleAnimationInterval = setInterval(function() {
      el.style.opacity = 0;
      setTimeout(function() {
        el.textContent = arr[current];
        el.style.opacity = 1;
        current = ++current % arr.length;
      }, self.options.transitionDuration);
    }, 4000);
  }

  function extend(out) {
    out = out || {};

    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      if (!arguments[i]) {
        continue;
      }

      for (var key in arguments[i]) {
        if (arguments[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          out[key] = arguments[i][key];
        }
      }
    }

    return out;
  }

}());
```

```html
<script>
//USAGE of library

//doesn't block the load event
window.addEventListener('load', function load() {
  window.removeEventListener('load', load); //remove listener, no longer needed

  new Widget({
    partnerId: '7a611bed-2530-4068-9d34-a0482bd9d626',
    departmentId: 4,
    channelId: 9,
    formHeaders: ['Header 1', 'Header 2', 'Header 3'],
    formText: 'Invite text',
    formPlaceholder: 'Placeholder text',
    photo: 23,
    color: '#000'
  });
});
</script>
```

Do you see any improvements / issues?

Comment: One improvement, yank out all the styles and use a stylesheet. No need to set tons of styles when one class would suffice.

Comment: Why the need for `this` everywhere? It's not needed, bloats the code and can be confusing when say I needed to really know that `this` is source of an event.

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS to setup your styles, and just giving items classes would cut this whole thing down to maybe a couple dozen lines.  You can even do all your animation with CSS, thereby letting the browser just do what it's there to do.

Actually, on a further look to see what this is actually doing -- Unless there's some purpose here that I'm completely missing, and you haven't explained -- there's only about 4 or 5 total lines of code here, the rest is all just simulating things you can do purely in CSS/HTML.

You should absolutely re-think how you're approaching this from square 1.  A few lines of HTML, a couple dozen lines of CSS, and 4 or 5 lines of Javascript would do this.

Comment: All my animation already created with css.